# What do I need to make a proper game console with a Raspberry Pi system?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I understand that what a lot of people have done (and what a lot of tutorials teach you to do) in order to create a game console with a raspberry pi is to install Retro PI. This is fun, but I believe that some people (including myself) would like to create a game console because they want to create a unique experience. In other words, I would like to create a game console using a raspberry pi 0 that doesn't use pre-made operating systems and pre-made games. I would like to know what I would need other than a screen, input, and a raspberry pi 0 itself to create what i'd call a "proper" game console. I would personally rather start from scratch if not a simple linux build for this console so that I can have full control over development. This way, I can have a good understanding of it and be able to create things like games and apps easier using my own pre-made tools. Kind of like Nintendo and developing game consoles themselves, but this one would be made by one person.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Perhaps you meant to post at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go is interesting to hang out with friends or alone, maybe this project will give you some ideas:  [maxvfischer / DIY-arcade](https://github.com/maxvfischer/DIY-arcade)

For development purposes, probably at least one Raspberry Pi in any of its flavors, all have limitations and advantages and disadvantages, in general without considering the graphics engine, the idea or any other program to compile, design or publish your games, its biggest challenge is the OS, maybe the best is a multiplatform development solution based on Java lang or JavaScript language or maybe HTML5 + Js.

A short list:
Rasperry Pi
Pick your programing languaje
Pick your development solution
Some free time
A lot of cofee or beer as you like
CNC + PAINT or 3d Print + Prototyping Services available in your area

1. [Rasperry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)
2. [Rasperry Pi Os List](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-raspberry-pi-os-available/)
3. [JavaScript Game Engines](https://www.slant.co/topics/768/%7Ebest-javascript-game-engines)
4. [HTML5 + JS game engines](https://www.edopedia.com/blog/open-source-html5-and-javascript-game-engines/)
5. [Gaming on Rasperry Pi](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/play-video-games-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer! This project will probably help me more with the hardware side. I will certainly take a bigger look at this when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for the hardware, I think a list of these items would be enough to get you up and running:

- Raspberry Pi of choice
- Screen
- Input (whatever you are planning on using, i think that for custom input, it might be
  best to use the existing GPIO pins to an extent)
- A power supply for Raspberry Pi

It gets a little complicated for software, but knowing that a simple Linux build was mentioned in your question, and the fact that it is possible, running a custom Linux version would be best for operating system. Although I cannot remember how to exactly set one up, the main reason I recommend one is because for a screen using the existing display port, you may need Linux based display drivers installed; having a Linux distro installed on your system will make it significantly easier to install display drivers.

Input is another complicated topic. If you are going to build a simple linux distro for your console, then the best option I can think of is to skip out on using a custom input system for the time being, and instead use a USB keyboard with keys which will be later mapped to controller inputs. For example, the Up, Down, Left, and Right keys on your keyboard could be mapped to the Dpad on your currently non-existant controller. Considering that USB keyboards are natively supported in the most recent versions of Linux, that might as well be (for the time being) your best input option.

If you want to know more about the tool that you can use to build a simple linux distro for a Raspberry Pi, I recommend reading more about it at [buildroot.org](https://www.buildroot.org) and trying it out for yourself.